# Computed column is of nullable type even though the column involves is of not null type

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a computed column.

I have a table say Table 1 that has a column called as Date of Joining.

I want to create a column that will return the value in Months(int) by subtracting the today date and the [Date of Joining] column.

I used this:  (datediff(month,[DateJoining],getdate()))

**And it works perfectly well but i dont know why the  computed type column is of null 
type even i made DateJoining column of not null type**

Any help is highly Appreciated.

Comment: Why do you care if the catalog views say the column is nullable? It's obviously not ever going to be null...

Comment: @AaronBertrand But i am wondering about this strange behaviour so i framed this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why SQL Server behaves this way, nor do I understand why it matters other than for understanding (which you won't really get because I don't know if anyone here can explain *why* this is the case). I think for an int it may be guarding against overflow (even though that is clearly not possible in this case).

If you really want the system catalog to confirm for you that the column is not nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.whatever ADD column_name 
  AS (ISNULL(datediff(month, DateJoining, getdate()), 0));
```

NB: This trick won't work with `COALESCE`.